# setAllowedFileTypes seems to break search ni NSOpenPanel

Tags: cocoa, osx-mavericks, nsopenpanel

It seems that if I call setAllowedFileTypes it breaks the search functionality of an NSOpenPanel on Mavericks. I have searched around and didn't find any details about this issue.

Here is my code to display my NSOpenPanel:

```
NSArray *allowedTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CSV",@"csv",nil];
NSOpenPanel *openDLG;
openDLG = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openDLG setAllowedFileTypes:allowedTypes];
[openDLG runModal];
```

If I don't call setAllowedFileTypes: I can search and find items just fine but if I do call it, the search never returns a valid response. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround? Is this somehow intended behavior? Or should I report this to apple?

Comment: Copied your code into my project and it's showing the search field. Is your app sandboxed? Which view does the panel show (list, icon, coverflow, column)? I saw this issue sometimes in other apps like Pages when the panel shows the iCloud first.

Comment: My app is not sandboxed, this happens in all of the views.

Comment: I recently had an interesting case here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692540/nsopenpanel-takes-longer-time-on-mac-osx-10-9/24709660?noredirect=1#comment38463034_24709660  where as signing the app solved issues with the NSOpenPanel.

Comment: We are having the same problem in all our products at soniccharge.com. The search-box is there but never shows any results. Removing setAllowedFileTypes: makes it work, but naturally the user can also select and open any kind of file, and that is much worse than not having search.

This behaviour is in at least OS X 10.8 and forwards.

Did you ever file a bug report to apple?