# NSOpenPanel takes longer time on Mac OSX 10.9

Tags: nsopenpanel

On Mac OSX 10.9,I am facing an issue with NSOpenPanel in My application.
NSopenpanel  takes longer time to launch it for the first time. 
I observed that [NSOpenPanel openPanel] takes longer time to execute for first time.Because of this it took some delay to launch for first time.Can any one suggest how to fix this issue

Comment: Did you try using Instruments to see where the time is spent?

Comment: Hi mahal tertin,
I am new to instruments app.Could you tell me which module in instruments to be use to track this kind of issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use the CPU Instrument. Also post the code here you're using to run the panel. Take care you're not using deprecated methods.

Comment: One observation is that if i launch application through instruments,OpenDialog launches fast even for the first time

Comment: so it's not your problem but the operating system. do you have complaints from users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because of the special architecture of the NSOpenPanel. The open panel  runs in it's own process called "Powerbox", especially if the app is sandboxed. The Powerbox does not have an API. Even if your app is not sandboxed, make sure you sign your app appropriately.

I'd love to point to some documentation about it, but the whole Powerbox and Sandbox are poorly documented and when introduced also poorly implemented.

Comment: My application is not sandboxed and it is not code signed also.Will it causing the issue

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Please post the code you're using to run the panel.

Comment: Hi mahal, Today i code sign the app & seems like it fixes this issue.Now open panel launches fast even for first time.Thank you very much for your support mahal